# I faced this problem while i was doing my react-native project

Tags: react-native, npm, react-navigation-stack

Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/stack" from "App.js"  undefined Unable to resolve module `@react-navigation/stack` from `App.js`: @react-navigation/stack  could not be found within the project.

Answer (score 0):

install react-navigation with `npm i react-navigation`

Answer (score 0):

From the react navigation docs: "To use this navigator, ensure that you have @react-navigation/native and its dependencies (follow this guide), then install @react-navigation/stack" (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator)

Assuming you already have react-navigation installed, you just need to install react-navigation stack `npm install @react-navigation/stack`

Otherwise, you should set up react navigation first: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/